# How to retrieve more than one data in email?

Tags: php, email

I have a table named 'laptop' and a column inside the table named 'Lap_War_Expiry'. I need to send an email to user when the warranty of the laptop is going to expire soon. For your information, there is more than one warranty that will expired in a day. But the code below is only send the same data from table 'laptop'. Why is that happened and what I have to add in the code so that the email send will retrieve two or more data from database ?

This is my coding for sending the email :

```
<?php
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" didn't worked
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';


// ======== get database data ==================
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$database="master_inventory";
mysql_select_db ($database,$link) OR die ("Could not open $database" );
$query = 'SELECT Lap_PC_Name, Lap_War_Expiry FROM laptop'; //xyz is id of desired user
name.
$result1 = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
  $Lap_PC_Name = $row['Lap_PC_Name'];
  $Lap_War_Expiry = $row['Lap_War_Expiry'];
 }

$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "somepassword";

$mail->IsHTML(true); // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails
$mail->SingleTo = true; 

$mail->From = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "AMS";
$mail->addAddress("emailaddress","AMS");
$mail->Subject = "Notification on warranty expiry";
$mail->Body = "Dear Madam,<br/><br />The licensed for the following PC will expired   
in less than one month.<br /><br /> PC Name : ".$Lap_PC_Name. "<br />Date of expired :"   
.$Lap_War_Expiry;

 if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 else
    echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move everything from below  your `while` loop into it.

**EDIT**
Change

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
  $Lap_PC_Name = $row['Lap_PC_Name'];
  $Lap_War_Expiry = $row['Lap_War_Expiry'];
 }
```

to

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
  $Lap_PC_Name = $row['Lap_PC_Name'];
  $Lap_War_Expiry = $row['Lap_War_Expiry'];

$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "somepassword";

$mail->IsHTML(true); // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails
$mail->SingleTo = true; 

$mail->From = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "AMS";
$mail->addAddress("emailaddress","AMS");
$mail->Subject = "Notification on warranty expiry";
$mail->Body = "Dear Madam,<br/><br />The licensed for the following PC will expired   
in less than one month.<br /><br /> PC Name : ".$Lap_PC_Name. "<br />Date of expired :"   
.$Lap_War_Expiry;

 if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 else
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about it ?

Comment: See my edit. The code for executing the `$mail->send` was only running once, for the first row it pulled from the database.

Comment: It's working now ! Thanks for your quick awesome answer. Never thought this is the solution. Thanks again Lain !