# Cannot retrieve all row in table php, only half is retrieved

Tags: php, email, row

I have a table named 'laptop' and a column inside the table named 'Lap_War_Expiry'. The code run well as what I have edit in previous posting, [How to retrieve more than one data in email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022152/how-to-retrieve-more-than-one-data-in-email) . However, the code only run for 45 data only. It supposed to be 100 data and sent the email to user. (I know it sounds too many of email, but before I try to combine the data in one email, I need to make sure all the data is retrieved first)

I try to change the php.ini config below but still cannot retrieve all the needed email. Is there anywhere that I should change other than this ? Or is it my configuration is not right ?

```
max_execution_time = 0     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 0  ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
;max_input_nesting_level = -1 ; Maximum input variable nesting level
memory_limit = 128M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
```

This is my coding for sending the email :

```
<?php
//class.phpmailer.php here

// ======== get database data ==================
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$database="master_inventory";
mysql_select_db ($database,$link) OR die ("Could not open $database" );
 $query2 = 'SELECT Lap_PC_Name, Lap_War_Expiry FROM laptop'; 
 name.
 $result1 = mysql_query($query2);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
$Lap_PC_Name = $row['Lap_PC_Name'];
$Lap_War_Expiry = $row['Lap_War_Expiry'];

$date=$row['Lap_War_Expiry'];
// $date is get from table
$date = date ('d-m-Y')||('d/m/Y') + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
$newdate = strtotime ( '+45 days' , strtotime ( $row['Lap_War_Expiry']) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'd/m/Y' , $newdate );
if ($newdate <45) {
$mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";

//sent email code is here

if(!$mail->Send())
echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   else
echo "Message has been sent";
}
  else {
 echo "No PC expired less than 45 days for today.    ";
    }
 }

?>
```

Comment: Too much code - consider trimming it down a bit

Answer (score 0):

I think `$newdate < 45` may have something to do with it.

Change this to 50 and I bet you get 50 records back. Or put an `else` statement so that if `$newdate > 45` you can see what is being printed.

Also, you should do logic in your SQL not in your PHP. You initial select query should do the filtering out. That would make it easier and faster.

Comment: I try what you have saying, but the email sent is only 45.

Comment: Can you call `mysql_num_rows` before your while loop and confirm how many rows your SQL is returning?